# TYPO3 extension: NewsSystem/ news (not tt_news)

Tags: typo3-6.2.x

I want to make a news site at my homepage. Therefore I am using the extension news system with the key news from extension manager.To embed a news article with image in teaser was no problem, but how to embed a youtube video in the teaser?

Somebody got an idea? Who is able to help me?

Answer (score 0):

You could extend your extension with a custom extension by adding a field for YouTube IDs. Then overwrite the template path to a new Teaser template via TS and copy/edit this template to show your YouTube iframe.